# How to access from AppleScript a bundled file within a Cocoa-AppleScript Application?

Tags: cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

In AppleScript I'm used to call:

```
set audio_file to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Audio:Music.mp3"
display dialog "Path: " & (quoted form of POSIX path of audio_file)
```

I have now this code inside a Cocoa-AppleScript project in Xcode. It compiles well, but the script is not running at all. The dialog never shows.

Without the `(path to me as string)` it works, but without the path.

Comment: I've found that the problem is the "me" part of _path to me as string_. If I use _path to home folder as string_ it works. The sub-question now is "How to self-reference the script folder if I can't use _me_?"

Comment: And the answer is that, in a Cocoa-AppleScript Application, the right sintaxis is NOT:

`(path to me as text)`

BUT:

`(path to current application as text)`

_me_ is not valid as self-reference. The correct one is _current application_.

Hope this helps others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is that, in a Cocoa-AppleScript Application, the right sintaxis is NOT:

```
(path to me as text)
```

BUT:

```
(path to current application as text)
```

`me` is not valid as self-reference. The correct one is `current application`.

Hope this helps others :)

Answer (score 1):

For resource file I use:

```
set fname to POSIX path of (path to resource "filename")
```

Answer (score 0):

"Path to me as string" seems correct but you could have 2 other problems. 1) the path to your audio file should contain "Contents" and not "Content". 2) In display dialog you don't need "quoted form" because posix path is a string and can be added to your "Path: " string with no problems. So check those 2 things and see if it helps.

**Edit:**
If the above doesn't help there's a "cocoa way to get the path to the application. I don't know the applescript-objc syntax but this is how you would get it via a cocoa method...

```
NSString* appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

And to get the path of a resource directly use this...

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Comment: "Content" was an error writing the question. And I'm with you that (path to me as string) seems correct. But: `display dialog (path to me as text)` doesn't work in Cocoa-AppleScript, and the problem is the _me_, because `display dialog (path to home folder as text)` works.

Comment: I added some cocoa code to my post which might help under the "edit" section.

Comment: AFAIK You can't mix Cocoa in an .applescript script :(

Comment: Sure you can. Your question states it's a Cocoa-Applescript app. So I assume you are writing it in Cocoa and running applescript code inside it. So you can calculate the appPath in cocoa and pass that to your applescript handler as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case though, you can just put the file in the root level of of the file tree in the XCode project, then do:

```
    set theFilePath to (path to resource "SomeFile.ext")
```

In my case I'm then doing:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        open theFilePath
    end tell
```

and it opens in its associated application.

When you distribute your application, 'SomeFile.ext' ends up in the Resources folder of your application package.

Not 100% sure how to specify a sub-folder as I haven't needed that so far, but I guess it'd be
`(path to resource "Audio:SomeFile.mp3")`?