# Applescript indicates resource not found when trying to call within inside the app

Tags: applescript

Playing with AppleScript I am confused on what I am doing wrong when I try to call another AppleScript from the `Scripts` folder.  My current script is saved as `foo.app` and I see the structure from the `Bundle Contents` but when I try to call `bar.app` from inside the `Scripts` folder I get a dialog of `Resource not found`.

After referencing "[How to access from AppleScript a bundled file within a Cocoa-AppleScript Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930726/how-to-access-from-applescript-a-bundled-file-within-a-cocoa-applescript-applica)" I tried:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thisFolder to (container of (path to me)) as string
    set insideApp to thisFolder & (path to resource "bar.app")
end tell
```

When that produced the error I did some more searching I referenced "[How do I get the Scripts folder in the application bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613142/how-do-i-get-the-scripts-folder-in-the-application-bundle)" and tried:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thisFolder to (container of (path to me)) as string
    set insideApp to (thisFolder as alias) & (path to resource "bar.app" in directory "Scripts")
end tell
```

Targeting `description.rtfd` I display the variable `thisFolder` and the dialog I get `Macintosh HD:Users:darth_vader:Desktop:` but it produces `Resource not found` when I run:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thisFolder to (container of (path to me)) as string
    display dialog thisFolder
    set insideApp to thisFolder & (path to resource "Contents:Resources:description.rtfd")
end tell
```

What exactly am I doing wrong and how do I call from within the `Scripts` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general misunderstanding:

`path to me` points to the path to the script (bundle).
`container of (path to me)` points to the path to the enclosing folder of the script (bundle)

So it's:

```
set insideApp to path to resource "bar.app"
```

or:

```
set insideApp to path to resource "bar.app" in directory "Scripts"
```

or (preferable)

```
set insideApp to alias ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:description.rtfd")
```

The `Finder` is not needed at all.